# Python Messenger Bot works only for admin, not for everyone

Tags: python, facebook, bots, facebook-messenger

I want to create sample Messenger Bot using code from this link
https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/12/facebook-messenger-bot-python.html

I setup ngrok and run code, but bot responding only for me(when I am on admin FB account). For others accounts, "bot" does not work.

1)I checked App Review --> Make "bot" public
2) In webhooks, I gave all possible permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until the bot is submitted for app review and approved for the pages_messaging permission, the bot can only interact with users that are assigned the tester, developer, or administrator app role. Also, the bot must be in development mode.

Once the app is switched to live mode, permissions are enforced and the bot will not even be able to interact with users that have one of those three app roles until the app is approved for pages_messaging.